# How to disable Home Screen wallpaper reposition?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, wallpaper

I'm a very "aesthethics guy" and it annoys me a lot that when I make my own wallpaper and set a new Home Screen wallpaper, WP changes its position (always moved a bit to the sides and up/bottom hidden). Is there a way to remove this reposition? AFAIK, WP does this to "add wallpaper" to the Installed Apps screen. [Example](https://imgur.com/a/FLsx2) (from bottom to top) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hm, could you provide screenshots to illustrate to problem? I don't know what you mean, to be honest.

Comment: @JohnArcher Added

Comment: @RowlandShaw, this is a WP10 problem only

Comment: For the "up/bottom" part it's about image size/resolution. For the "to the sides" part, it's just how the Windows 10 Mobile home screen wallpaper works. If you really want your image not to reach the "sides" you can add a black image, that will work as wallpaper for the apps list. But then again, trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

You can't.

---

You already described the problem - Windows Mobile extends the wallpaper to the "Installed Apps" list, where you find the "rest" of you wallpaper. This is a similar behaviour of the old panorama/hub behaviour when scolling sideways.

Guess the only workaround is to "try and error" the size of the piece of the picture you want to show, which means try a bigger image section when choosing the background picture until it fits into you start screen.

Comment: I actually can't downvote (rep on this site), but I was going to. I knew that try and error but this answer does solve any of the two main question I asked: "How to disable Home Screen wallpaper reposition?" and "Is there a way to remove this reposition?". If I understood correctly, it'd be "You can't"... but if then, could you explicitly say it? :p

Comment: Why did you want to downvote?

Ok, to say it explicitly: you can't.

Comment: Answer too long and not clear

Comment: Pffff :-/ Clearly, the first thing you want to do is to downvote instead to add a comment. Guys like you are the reason why one is stopping to help others.

Comment: didn't I add a comment? I was going to downvote and add a comment, as I did. I didn't even downvote because I don't have enough rep. That's why downvote and upvote were created: to rate a answer/question. It's nothing personal, just a qualification